# org.apache.http.HttpException: Unsupported Content-Coding: none

Tags: java, http, apache-httpcomponents

I am using Apache HTTP Components to send a POST request to a server that is not owned by me (therefore I cannot modify its configuration).

The server, in response back to me, sets `Content-Encoding: none` header which causes the `org.apache.http.HttpException: Unsupported Content-Coding: none` exception.

I found somewhere on StackOverflow that I can use `HttpClients.custom().disableContentCompression().build()` to disable `RequestAcceptEncoding` and `ResponseContentEncoding` interceptors, therefore making the exception not to be thrown. However, I do not want to reconfigure my `HttpClient` in that way globally.

Is there any workaround of this issue without adding changes to `HttpClient`?

As a note, I do not have to read response body at all, as it's empty. I just need to be able to read response code (ie. `200 OK`).

Thank you for your time.

Comment: The server's response is invalid. Did you report the bug?

Comment: Sadly, reporting the bug will not help in this case, as the owners of the server will not fix it. This one I am certainly sure, as I know them. I have to find some workaround on my side.

Comment: I have decided that I will simply put the HttpClient.execute() in a try-catch with empty catch block around for that exception until I find a real solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after months I found the solution for this problem!

There is a workaround with using interceptors to fix the bad Content-Encoding header, [see this blog entry](http://adamscheller.com/java/httpexception-unsupported-content-coding-none-solution/).

Answer (score -1):

I met similar problem. A simple fix is to disable compression in the http client builder.

```
HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpClients.custom();
clientBuilder.disableContentCompression();
HttpClient client = clientBuilder.build();
```